# apache route mapping for node app

Tags: node.js, apache, httpd.conf

I have url like this `http://myste.com/n/marketplace`
Where `http://myste.com` - is a java app, `/n/` - is node instance, `/marketplace` - one of the nodes routes.

How to configure apache so that route `http://myste.com/marketplace` was the same as `http://myste.com/n/marketplace`?

I will be having node routes like `http://myste.com/n/marketplace and http://myste.com/n/tips` with their respective namespaces.

How do I get rid of `/n/`? And what the relative path to public static files would be?

I've tried something like this, and it worked except my static files were not found.

```
ProxyPass    /marketplace    http://localhost:3000/marketplace
ProxyPassReverse /marketplace    http://localhost:3000/marketplace

ProxyPass    /tips    http://localhost:3000/tips
ProxyPassReverse /tips    http://localhost:3000/tips
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_proxy doesn't allow you manipulate the requested URL.

You'd be better off using the proxy switch in mod_rewrite rather than mod_proxy.

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/$1 [P,QSA,L]
```